# HTTP Status 404-Not Found

Tags: spring, tomcat, http-status-code-404

Yo, im building my first Spring Web App.
When i try to run it (On server) this is the response

TTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message /HelloWorld/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

hierarchy
[image]

web.xml 
[image]

dispatcher-servlet.xml 
[image]

helloworld.jsp 
[image]

Controller 
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. [Instead of screenshots please copy and paste your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

the page you're requesting from browser is not found, so you need to add url in below pattern:
 localhost:(Port number) /project name/(request mapping at controller) /(request mapping at method)

Comment: it WOKS! Thanks man

Comment: @Nicholas Ferrari  please accept jiket 's answer.